# dynamic cast for references

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, reference-type

I use dynamic cast for safety:

here is the code I use with pointers:

```
XYZ xyz = dynamic_cast<XYZ*>(abc);
if (xyz == nullptr)
{
    // TODO handle error
}
```

Now is there a way to do the same but with references:

```
XYZ& xyz = dynamic_cast<XYZ&>(abc);
if (xyz == nullptr)
{
    // TODO handle error
}
```

this code doesn't compile but I am asking is there a way to do that in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dynamic_cast` throws an exception on failure if used with references. To handle failure, catch the exception:

```
try {
    XYZ& xyz = dynamic_cast<XYZ&>(abc);
}
catch (std::bad_cast& e) {
    //handle error
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but since you're casting to a reference, `nullptr` is not a possible outcome. Instead, if the dynamic type of `abc` is not convertible to `XYZ`, the cast will throw `std::bad_cast`.

Comment: so that mean that in cast of pointers a nullptr is returned while in case of references an exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.